# SQL Server Auditing Data in the Same Table

Tags: sql, audit-tables, audit-logging

A project I'm working on requires that a record be digitally "signed" and after that any modifications would create a new "version" of the row. The "signed" record can't be modified for regulatory reasons and new versions shouldn't be modified very often. In the past, done so by creating a separate logging table with the same schema as the main table with some extra columns for tracking who modified it and when.

However, after doing some work with SharePoint where ALL data (including different versions) is put into the same table I thought of a different approach which I can't find any examples of people doing: I could put the new version of the row right in the same table and increment the version number. Then add the version number to the PK.

PROS:

- Implementation is easy, just create an "Instead of update" trigger which performs an insert instead of an update of the row is "signed". I could easily add a IsCurrentVersion column to be updated in the trigger.
- Querying for older versions is easy, just get all the records with
  the ID I want let the user choose from the list.
- A trigger is nice because it guarantees that a row CAN'T be updated if signed (for regulatory and audit purposes).
- Schema changes to the table don't have to be replicated to the mirror "logging" table.

CONS:

- The table *could* get a bit larger but most of the time the record won't be changed after "signing" it. The client estimated around 100,000 rows/year max at current usage levels. SQL Server can handle hundreds of millions of rows so this doesn't seem too bad.
- Indexing and performance could be an issue. SharePoint adds a tp_CalculatedVersion int to the PK where the calculated number is always 0 for the latest version. I could do the same and calculate it based off the Version number. **Would that help performance?**
- There is an extra step in querying the data to make sure you get the latest version but that could be handled in a SP.
- **What other cons are there in this scenario. Am I missing anything??**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the requirement is that the signed data not be changed, then you should move it to another table.  In fact, I might suggest moving it to another database/schema, where the only operation allowed on the table is inserting and reading records.  You can use both permissions *and* triggers, if you really want to prevent updates.

You don't want to mess around with regulatory requirements.  A complex schema that uses a combination of primary key with version, along with triggers, is a sign that there might be a simpler way.

The historical records can affect performance of the current records.  If you end up in a situation where every record has changed 100 times, then keeping them in the same table is just going to slow down queries.  Of course, you can embark on more complexity, in the form of partitioning the data.  In the end, the solution is simpler:  keep the data that cannot be changed in another table where it cannot be changed.  You don't want to have to upgrade the hardware just because lots of history has accumulated.

I would also suggest including an effective and end date in the history records.  This will allow you to reconstruct all the data as of a particular date, something that users might find useful in the future.

Comment: If you ship the "signed" records to another database then effectively the only records in the main table would be "Drafts"? That would mean that the table is almost always empty (seems strange to me).

Comment: There should be a current table which has the most recent versions of all records, whether signed or not.  The history table would maintain the requirements for auditing, which would be all signed records.

Comment: Okay, that's pretty much how I've done it in the past, sans-extra DB. So the main CON you see is that of extra complexity? The issue of extra records is not an issue since they will rarely edit it after signing.

Comment: @JimBrown . . . the main cons are both performance and complexity.  The issue with complexity is failing the auditing requirement, which is hard to detect and fix.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this pattern used in an enterprise system before,and IMO it wasn't successful.

- You are Mixing two different concerns here, viz storage of live and audit data. Queries to this table will always need to keep in mind whether they are seeking leaf or audit data (e.g. reports) - new team members may find this non intuitive. You would likely need to encapsulate this complexity with views etc.
- As you mentioned performance will always be a concern. Inserting a new record will also need to update the previous record to mark it as inactive.You may also need to consider changing your clustered index to keep all versions on the same page.
- Foreign keys to this table are going to be problematic. Do you
  reference an exact version record? Do you then fix up the foreign
  keys to point to the new live leaf record?

The one benefit I can think of doing this is that the audit table DDL will always be in synch with the live table - often with the 2 table strategy changes are made to the live, and the audit and trigger DDL isn't updated accordingly.

Overall, I would still recommend keeping your audit table separate.

Answer (score 1):

That's right.  Audit trails can stay in an application for internal reporting/audit but infosec best practice mandates getting audit logs off the system where they are generated into your log management / SIEM solution.